Maximum call stack size exceeded Next 14
I have a server component where I fetch some categories after which I pass those categories to a client component to map through. But I get "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error.
here is the code.
/categories/page.js
import CategoryList from '@/components/CategoryList'

async function Home({ params }) {
 const all_categories = await getCategories() //fetches categories from an API
 
return(
<div>
  <h1>Here is a list of categories...</h1>
  <CategoryList list={all_categories.data} />
</div>
)
}

export default Home

/components/CategoryList.js
'use client'

import {useState} from 'react'

const CategoryList = (props) => {
  
  const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState({}) 
 
  return (
     <div>
      {props.list.map((category, index) => {
        <h2 onClick={()=>setSelectedCategory(category)}>
          {category.name}​
        </h2>;
      })}
    </div>
);
};

export default Candidates;




The code you posted should not generate that error. Is it possibly coming from getCategories? I recommend adding some error handling around your data fetching.

Looks like you are not returning anything from the map function. can be written as:
 const CategoryList = (props) => {
  const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState({});

  return (
    <div>
      {props.list.map((category, index) => (
        <h2 key={index} onClick={() => setSelectedCategory(category)}>
          {category.name}
        </h2>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};


That's true and a good point, but doesn't actually answer the question: failing to return something from a map method will not overflow the callstack.
